# Update Centos Machine 5.10 to 6.5

Tags: centos, cpanel, updates, whm

I want to update my dedicate Centos Machine, which installed WHM. I want to know that if I do update the OS, there any changes on WHM. Like any default Setting changed? or any other Problems.

So please suggest me that right way of update Centos without any problems, because many websites hosted on this Server.

Thanks 
Pankaj Gupta

Answer (score 0):

Pankaj, because there are many changes in a major CentOS release you cannot upgrade from 5.10 to 6.5. You need to put together a migration plan. First install CentOS 6.5 on another server, configure httpd and php/passenger/whichever and test that each hosted website is working properly. Then you can reinstall and reconfigure everything.

Give CentOS 7 a try.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading is not possible and even if you try around doing some search you will end up wasting lot of time by fixing the dependency related errors etc. So its always better and safe to do a fresh install of CentOS 6.5 and then migrate the sites.